# How to modify this javascript code to grab an image URL from a JSON file, and display it in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json

The code is for a Trivia Game, which was freely available to use.  I have modified it to add features and the over all look.  The game works.   But I need to display an image for each question.

The JSON file contains the questions, each is an object, with the question, choices, answer data and a URL to an image (the json file is simply questions.json and the URL key is "media").

Example: (including just in case I have an error with the URL format in the json file itself)

{
"subject": "World News",
"level":  "Easy",
"media":  "/img/trivia000.png",
"question": "Which one was the worlds worst nuclear power plant disaster?",
"choice1": "Chernobyl (Ukraine)",
"choice2": "Fukushima (Japan)",
"choice3": "Kyshtym (Soviet Union)",
"choice4": "Windscale (United Kingdom)",
"answer": 1
}

The HTML div is simply "content1" for the image, and "content2" contains the game itself.

There are plenty of examples out there which shows calling the json file and some parsing the data and other version not parsing the data.   My problem is the code I am using is already calling the the json file and manipulating the data in a way the game needs and every method I have tried to incorporate into the javascript causes the game to stop working.

The most success I have had is with:  content1.innerHTML = currentQuestion.media;  This will show the file name in the div.

Heres the JS file:

```
    const question = document.getElementById('question');
    const choices = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('choice-text'));
    const progressText = document.getElementById('progressText');
    const scoreText = document.getElementById('score');
    const progressBarFull = document.getElementById('progressBarFull');
    const loader = document.getElementById('loader');
    const game = document.getElementById('game');
    const media = document.getElementById('media');
    let currentQuestion = {};
    let acceptingAnswers = false;
    let score = 0;
    let questionCounter = 0;
    let availableQuesions = [];

    let questions = [];


    fetch('/json/questions.json')
    .then((res) => {
     return res.json()
 
    })

    .then((loadedQuestions) => {
    questions = loadedQuestions;
    startGame();

    })

    .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    });


    //CONSTANTS
    const CORRECT_BONUS = 10;
    const MAX_QUESTIONS = 50;

    startGame = () => {
    questionCounter = 0;
    score = 0;
    availableQuesions = [...questions];
    getNewQuestion();
    game.classList.remove('hidden');
    loader.classList.add('hidden');
    };

    getNewQuestion = () => {
    if (availableQuesions.length === 0 || questionCounter >= MAX_QUESTIONS) {
        localStorage.setItem('mostRecentScore', score);
        //go to the end page
        return window.location.assign('/end.html');
    }
    questionCounter++;
    progressText.innerText = `Question ${questionCounter}/${MAX_QUESTIONS}`;
    //Update the progress bar
    progressBarFull.style.width = `${(questionCounter / MAX_QUESTIONS) * 100}%`;

    const questionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableQuesions.length);
    currentQuestion = availableQuesions[questionIndex];
    question.innerHTML = currentQuestion.question;

    //New Code New Code New Code New Code New Code New Code

    subject.innerHTML = currentQuestion.subject;
    level.innerHTML = currentQuestion.level;
    content1.innerHTML = currentQuestion.media;
    
    
    
    //New Code New Code New Code New Code New Code New Code 


    choices.forEach((choice) => {
        const number = choice.dataset['number'];
        choice.innerHTML = currentQuestion['choice' + number];
    });

    availableQuesions.splice(questionIndex, 1);
    acceptingAnswers = true;
    };



    choices.forEach((choice) => {
    choice.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if (!acceptingAnswers) return;

        acceptingAnswers = false;
        const selectedChoice = e.target;
        const selectedAnswer = selectedChoice.dataset['number'];
        const classToApply =
            selectedAnswer == currentQuestion.answer ? 'correct' : 'incorrect';

        if (classToApply === 'correct') {
            incrementScore(CORRECT_BONUS);
        }

        selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.add(classToApply);

        setTimeout(() => {
            selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.remove(classToApply);
            getNewQuestion();
        }, 750);
    });
});

    incrementScore = (num) => {
    score += num;
    scoreText.innerText = score;
};
```

Comment: `content1.innerHTML = \`<img src="${currentQuestion.media}">\`;` perhaps?

Comment: Thank You Nick !    I tried several variations of this, and nothing would work.   I copied and pasted yours into VS code and it worked immediately.   Pat

Comment: Good to hear! I'm glad I could help